# Java scanner run on only first line of method why not middle

Tags: java, methods

I am newbie in Java but want to know why Scanner input system only work in first line of code in method not in middle of below code as Java works line by line they should ask for input whenever they hit scanner input code...or i am doing something wrong

```
public void go(){        
 try{         
     Socket soc= new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
     PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
     Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in) ;
     String txt=s.next();
     pw.println(txt);
     pw.flush();
     pw.close();
 }catch(Exception e){

 }        
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting as I'm having difficulty understanding what your problem is? Your code calls `s.next()` once and therefore only reads one line.

Comment: You have to iterate through the file to read all the lines.

Comment: The `next()` method reads the next **token**.  With the default token delimiters that will be at most one line.

Comment: if u run the above code the compiler completes the build that is"BUILD SUCCESSFULLY" but it didn't ask for input...but if i put the scanner and string above the socket line then it ask for input by keyboard.

Comment: Catch and Fix the exception in socket.Your scanner will start working....

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate a loop:

```
public void go(){        
  try{         
     Socket soc= new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
     PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
     Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in) ;
     while(true){
        String txt=s.next();
        pw.println(txt);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
     }
  }catch(Exception e){

 }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is this:

```
catch (Exception e){

}
```

This says, "catch all exceptions **and don't tell me what happened**"

At least do this:

```
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to find out what the exception was.  That will give you some clues for the next problem.  (Which is probably nothing to do with the `Scanner`. I expect the problem is with `soc.getOutputStream()`.)

Comment: Yes Stephen C you r right the problem is not associated with scanner the print stack dosent name scanner anywhere,even i know the solution for this is to just put scanner and next() code above the socket and it will ask for input...but as i am exploring little into Java my understanding says Java execute line by line so when they reach the code {String txt= s.next()} they should ask for input but it didn't, now if i put it above socket it dose ask for input ,i want to know how it work behind the scene.

Comment: @rachit3dev the problem is that your code doesn’t reach that point because of that exception. After the exception the rest of the code in ‘try’ is ignored and the program will execute the code in the ‘catch’ block. But there is no code in your ‘catch’ block so you didn’t notice this. Fix the exception first and then your code execution will continue to the scanner line.

Comment: @rachit3dev and congratulations! Very early in your programming career you have found out that ‘swallowing’ exceptions like this makes it very hard to see what’s wrong.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek You are awesome,i just got to know what i am doing wrong,and thanks u just understand the core of my problem....now whenever i ran above code with serversocket running it ask for scanner input bcoz it finds connection and dosent throw exception so the code moves completely throughout the try block...gr8